# INSTEAD OF INSERT does not display changes

Tags: sql-server, trigger, insert, sequence, entity-framework

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [GroupId]     INT        NOT NULL,
    [ItemId]      INT        NOT NULL,
    [Data]        INT        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GroupId], [ItemId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_tblGroup] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupId]) REFERENCES [tblGroup] ([Id])
);
```

I used this trigger to generate `ItemID` on insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger_MyTable_OnInsert]
ON [MyTable]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable([GroupId], [ItemId], [Data])
    SELECT [GroupId],
        ISNULL((SELECT MAX(ItemId)
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE MyTable.GroupId = GroupId), 0) + 1,
        [Data]
    FROM  inserted i
END
```

At insert time, the new `ItemId` value is inserted into the table but is not displayed:

[image: inserted row]

This problem also exists when working with the Entity Framework and I found the problem with this part of the database.

I'm trying to get an `ItemId` sequence for each `GroupId`. `ItemId` is unique to each group, not the table, that's why I can't use `IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the point that i have to use `OUTPUT` command.

> [Using OUTPUT in an INSTEAD OF trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#h-using-output-in-an-instead-of-trigger)

This is Fixed SQL Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger_MyTable_OnInsert]
ON [MyTable]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable([GroupId], [ItemId], [Data])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[ItemId] as [ItemId]
    SELECT [GroupId],
        ISNULL((SELECT MAX(ItemId)
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE MyTable.GroupId = GroupId), 0) + 1,
        [Data]
    FROM  inserted i
END
```

And as I said, this problem exists when using **EntityFrameworkCore**. To solve this problem, we must tell Entity Framework that this value will change after call the `Add()` method.

To solve this problem, it is enough to add the following method in the **DbContext** class:

```
entity.Property(table => table.ItemId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

To be clear, the result of the code is as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.GroupId, e.ItemId });
        entity.Property(table => table.ItemId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.ToTable("MyTable");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question directly, the problem is:

```
WHERE MyTable.GroupId = GroupId
```

You haven't specified which `GroupId` you mean on the right hand side of that expression.

The SQL standard dictates that SQL Server must resolve it to the innermost scope, so you have effectively written:

```
WHERE MyTable.GroupId = MyTable.GroupId
```

You should instead write:

```
WHERE MyTable.GroupId = i.GroupId
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ed3698840f79f9922379b2fe70e8d91)

The trigger has other problems, such as not handling multi-row inserts properly, and not being safe under concurrency.

A related article of mine: [Sequence Tables](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/10/sequence-tables.html).